# CS50 Pset5, runs fine with large dictionary but seg faults on small dictionary

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable, cs50

I am having some problems with PSET 5 of the CS50 course. This is the speller problem. My code Segfaults when I try to load the small dictionary.

After debugging with gdb, it shows that the error occurs when I'm trying to fopen(dictionary, "r") on line 83.

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // fopen dictionary file (remb to check if NULL)
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return false;
    }
```

It returns "Could not open file\n"). But I can't figure out why this is happening, can anyone help? Everything for the large dictionary seems to be running fine.

Full code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 256;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Word_count for size function
unsigned long word_count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    char small_word[LENGTH+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
    {
        small_word[i] = 0;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(isupper(word[i]))
        {
            small_word[i] = tolower(word[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            small_word[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    // hash the word to get hash value
    unsigned long hvalue = hash(small_word);

    // point cursor to the first value in the table with index of hvalue
    node* cursor = table[hvalue];

    // as long as the strings don't match, we reassign cursor to the next value
    while (strcasecmp(small_word, cursor->word) != 0)
    {
        cursor = cursor->next;
        // since strings dont match, if they reach to the end where next is NULL
        if (cursor == NULL)
        {
            // then the word is misspelled
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned long hash(const char *word)
{
    // djb2 hash function as seen from http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html
    unsigned long hash = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = *word++))
    {
        hash = c + (hash << 6) + (hash < 16) - hash;
    }
    return (hash % N);
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // fopen dictionary file (remb to check if NULL)
    FILE *dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return false;
    }

    char storage[LENGTH + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++)
    {
        storage[i] = 0;
    }

    while (fscanf(dict, "%s", storage) != EOF)
    {
        // allocate space for buffer node
        node *buffer = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // copy the string in storage into the buffer node
        strcpy(buffer->word, storage);

        // hash the word to obtain hvalue
        unsigned long hvalue = hash(buffer->word);
        
        // assigns buffer's next to point to the current words inside the table
        buffer->next = table[hvalue];
        
        // after making sure that buffer next keeps the address of the other words, you assign the table hvalue to the most recent word
        table[hvalue] = buffer;
        
        // increase word count by one
        word_count++;
        
    }

    fclose(dict);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned long size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    word_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = table[i];
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
        
        free(cursor);
    }
        
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to assign `0` to all elements of `small_word`. Just add a null terminator after the loop that copies all the characters.

Comment: You must be using the wrong filename for the dictionary.

Comment: How are you getting the dictionary filename?

Comment: If the `fopen` line causes the SIGSEGV, it would indicate that `dictionary` isn't a pointer to a valid, NUL-terminated string. Since you don't show `load` being called, we can't help you. Please provide a minimal, *runnable* demonstration of the problem as required. See [mcve]

Comment: Your description of the problem is inconsistent. If you're getting a segfault during `fopen()` you wouldn't get to the line that prints `Could not open file`

Comment: @Barmar thanks! I added a null terminator after the loop and it does the same thing as my previous loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Could not open file" message is probably a typo on the command line (as mentioned in the comments, it doesn't  produce a seg fault because it gives the message, then returns `false` to speller, and speller gives a message and exits).

Try debug50 with a breakpoint set at `node* cursor = table[hvalue];` in check. Use `texts/cat.txt` as the text file. Once you step into the next line, program will more than likely seg fault.

The small dictionary (supplied with the distro code) does not populate all members of `table`. If `table[index]` is not populated, there is not such thing as `table[index]->next` or `table[index]->word`. This `while (strcasecmp(small_word, cursor->word) != 0)` therefore, is a seg fault waiting to happen.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was having trouble finding the source of the seg fault. After seeing your answer, I added an if statement to check for the case of NULL and it solved my problem.